# Optimization in discrete steps

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Say I have a monotonous increasing value function $$f(x,y)$$ with $$x,y \in \mathbb{N}$$ where I am at any point in the $x$, $y$ plane. I can only "move" on the function by increasing either x or y by a set value (say for for this example exactly $1$ but any natural number $n$ might be possible).

Can I find the "optimal choice" of weather to move in the $x$ or $y$ direction (so I want to find out if $f(x+1,y)$ or $f(x, y+1)$ will be greater without evaluating both every time) by finding the partial derivatives $\nabla f$ at $(x,y)$ and looking up which one is greater or is there more to it?

As a direct example of why I want to find this out: Let $f$ be a damage calculation formula in a (video)game and I want to know which of the two stats that my character has to improve. Basically the path by using the derivatives should tell me "choosing $x$ over $y$ is always better".

To make matters more interesting, say I have a choice of increasing $x$ by $n$ and $y$ by a different value $m$. Can the derivate tell me anything about my choice here without looking at $f(x + n, y)$ or $f(x, y + m)$? The question here would be "stat y need to be improved by this much more than x to be worth the choice".

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't have a gradient.  It doesn't have partial derivatives.  You are unable to take the limits for the gradient and partial derivatives.

This is even hopeless if you have an $f$ defined on the plane.  Consider
$$  f(x,y) = \cos(2\pi x) x + \cos(2 \pi y) y  \text{.}  $$
As a discrete function, it is strictly monotonically increasing in both $x$ and $y$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a continuous function, the derivatives are noninformative.  (You haven't required that $f$ is monotonic or even continuous as a function on the real plane.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would adding that $f$ is a polynom (as most functions used for calculation in games are) help?

Comment: No.  It is straightforward to make polynomials that replace the cosines in my example.  For instance, $f(x,y) = \left(x^{11}-55 x^9+1023 x^7-7645 x^5+21076 x^3-14400 x+1\right) x + \left(y^{11}-55 y^9+1023 y^7-7645 y^5+21076 y^3-14400 y+1\right) y$.

Comment: You also said that the function might be monotonous in $\mathbb{N}$ but non-monotonous in $\mathbb{R}$, but what if all worse case scenarios are not the case, as the function is quite simple (e.g. $a + bx^2 + cy$), would any information about $\nabla f$ help?